# What does a numbered dot mean on a sectional chart?

Tags: faa, aeronautical-charts

[image: Point on Sectional.]

What does this point (125) mean on a Sectional Chart?

Is it the field elevation, or just the highest elevation on the area?

Answer (score 6):

It’s a local elevation at a particular point, generally in a flat area as a reference base elevation for the area.